# javascript check if text anchor text inside a link overflows

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to check if the anchor text overflows when i have this css/html ?

```
<a href="#" style"overflow:hidden; width:100px; display:block;>
    This is a very long text. This is a very long text. This is a very long text.
</a>
```

i use Jquery or pure javascript

Comment: are you wanting to cut automatically if link is too long? or just looking for a way to see if the text goes past a certain width ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the text content to an tmp element, then calculates it width compare it with `<a>` width to check if the content overflows or not. See below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/SvNEa/2/)

```
$('a').on('click', function () {
    var $tmp = $('<a/>')
                .text($(this).text())
                .css('display','none')
                .appendTo('body');
    alert(($tmp.width() > $(this).width())?'Overflows':'Perfectly Inside');
    $tmp.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i=0,len=as.length;i<len;i++){
    var that = as[i]
        w = that.offsetWidth,
        w2 = that.scrollWidth;
    if (w<w2) {
        console.log("This content overran!");
    }
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ArdsZ/1/).

---

Pretty much the above, but the following also adds a 'reporting' element to the DOM:

```
var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i=0,len=as.length;i<len;i++){
    var that = as[i],
        w = that.offsetWidth,
        w2 = that.scrollWidth,
        s = document.createElement('span');
    if (w<w2) {
        var text = document.createTextNode('This content overran the container, a, element by ' + (w2-w) + 'px.');
        s.appendChild(text);
        that.parentNode.insertBefore(s,that.nextSibling);
    }
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ArdsZ/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div id="parent" style="overflow:hidden; width:100px;display:block">
 <a id="textblock" href="#" style="white-space: nowrap;" >
     This 
 </a>
</div>
<script>
  var p=document.getElementById("parent");
  var tb=document.getElementById("textblock");
  (p.offsetWidth<tb.offsetWidth)?alert('long'):alert('short');
</script>​
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**:

```
<a id="a1" href="#" style="overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:10px; display:block">
    This is a very long text. This is a very long text. This is a very long text.
</a>
<a id="a2" href="#" style="width:100px; height:10px; display:block">
    This is a very long text. This is a very long text. This is a very long text.
</a>
```

**JS**:

```
function hasOverflow( $el ){
    return $el.css("overflow")==="hidden" &&  
          ($el.prop("clientWidth") < $el.prop("scrollWidth") || 
           $el.prop("clientHeight") < $el.prop("scrollHeight"));
}
console.log( hasOverflow($("#a1")) );       //true
console.log( hasOverflow($("#a2")) );       //false
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/p3LC8/)